# Отправка URL сайта на мой сервер при исполнении скрипта

Tags: php, mysql

Написал свой простенький скрипт, как оказалось очень полезный и стоящий денег. Не хочу чтобы мой "друг" продавал вне кассы, как говорится, так что возник вопрос.

Как мне отсылать на мой сервер URL сайта, где открылся файл index.php допустим?

Comment: Это денег стоит, награду надо назначить

Comment: @11111000000 , 5$ что есть то есть.

Comment: Вопрос миллион раз обсуждался на SO. Ответ - никак. Тот, у кого будет исходник спокойно сможет его исправить под себя и убрать оттуда всю защиту, если конечно тот не полный идиот.....если я правильно вопрос понял :-D

Comment: его как друга можно попросить ничего не трогать

Answer (score 1):

Получаем адрес, например [так](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php), отправляем, допустим [так](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php).

А вообще [вот как это делается](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SaaS).